# Unity CustomEditor deletes List parameters after Unity Restart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a custom Editor Script to display and adjust parameters of elements in a Reorderable List. But whenever I restart Unity and click the GameObject holding the script, these parameters are reseted (like shown in the picture at the end of the post). When I deactivate the Custom Editor Script, everything works as it should, so the problem might be in this script.

This is the *Story* class using the custom Editor script:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Story : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Chapter> ChapterList;
}
```

and the Editor Script, using a Reorderable List:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Story))]
public class StoryEditor : Editor 
{
private Story story;
private ReorderableList reorderableList;

void OnEnable()
{
    story = (Story) target;
    if (story.ChapterList == null)
        story.ChapterList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Chapter>();
    if (reorderableList == null)
        reorderableList = 
            new ReorderableList(
                story.ChapterList,
                typeof(Chapter), 
                true, true, true, true);

    reorderableList.drawElementCallback += DrawElement;
}

private void DrawElement(Rect rect, int index, bool active, bool focused)
{
    Chapter c = story.ChapterList[index];
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    c.ID = index+1;
    EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, 20, rect.height-1), c.ID);
    c.Title = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(rect.x + 21, rect.y, rect.width - 79, rect.height-1), c.Title);
    c.Hide  = EditorGUI.Toggle(new Rect(rect.x + rect.width - 56, rect.y, 17, rect.height-1), c.Hide);

    if (GUI.Button(
        new Rect(
            rect.x + rect.width - 40, rect.y, 40, rect.height-1), "Edit"))
                Select(index);

    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    }
}
```

I googled the problem, but the solutions I found mentioned to use *[System.Serializable]* and *EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);*, which I'm using both. I assume I'm missusing something in the "DrawElement" method, but I can't figure out what it is.

[image: Image displaying the changes pre and post restarting Unity]

*Upper part: Before Restarting, Lower Part: After Restarting Unity.*

Comment: Maybe you could compare your code to [this answer on Unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/826062/re-orderable-object-lists-in-inspector.html). I haven't used any of this myself though.

Comment: Thanks! But this was the guide I was following, causing this problem.

Comment: Well, it does look significantly different from that, specifically that `Story` has `[Serializable]` rather than `Chapter` (which I don't know if it also has `[Serializable]` because I don't have its code). You also don't appear to call `SetDirty` when items are added/removed, although maybe you've determined that's not necessary in your case. I guess what I'm suggesting is that you use this debug approach: use code identical to something that works for people and change it to what you think you need one step at a time to isolate what small change causes problems.

Comment: Thanks! I will rego through the code adding parts from the working solution.
I've shortened the code example above drastically, `Add/Remove` also call `SetDirty` and `Chapter` is `[Serializable]` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems I've encountered while working on this issue. First: The if statement in the Editors `OnEnable()` method is true everytime you reselect the object holding the Story script. This seems to be because of the way Editor Scripts are working. I think they're reinstantiated whenever the user reselects the object. Therefore I moved the `new List<Chapter>();` part to the Story class and implemented a *Getter* functionality.

```
private List<Chapter> chapterList;
public  List<Chapter> ChapterList
{
    get 
    { 
        if (chapterList == null)
            chapterList = new List<Chapter>();
        return chapterList;
    }
}
```

The next issue were the private variables. While public variables are always serializable, private values will not be serialized (allthough the class is marked as `[System.Serializable]`, which I thought would solve this problem). To make private variables Serializeable, they have to be marked as a `[SerializeField]`.

```
[SerializeField]
private List<Chapter> chapterList;
public  List<Chapter> ChapterList
{
    get 
    { 
        if (chapterList == null)
            chapterList = new List<Chapter>();
        return chapterList;
    }
}
```

After I add `[SerializeField]` to every private variable in my classes, the problem was gone.